# Describe quaternion solutions to $x^2-3x+3=0$

Tags: polynomials, quaternions

So I have the complex solutions $\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. And I want to describe the rest of the solutions, which I think are supposed to be rotations of these. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Can I just pick any unit quarternion as an axis and all rotations of these solutions are solutions?

Comment: is it supposed to be $\frac32+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$?

Comment: The complex numbers are sufficient to find all algebraic numbers.  Quaternions are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Ugly solution.

Let $x=a+bi+cj+dk$ be any quaternion.

Then
$$x^2=(a+bi+cj+dk)^2=..\\
-3x=-3a-3b-3c-3d \\
x^2-3x+3=...$$

**Nicer solution**

If you are familiar with the Matrix representation of the quaternions, the problem becomes simpler.
You want a matrix $$X= \begin{bmatrix} a+bi & c+di \\ -c+di & a-bi \end{bmatrix}$$
satisfying
$$X^2-3X+3I =0 $$

Now, the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $\mathbb C$ is either linear or quadratic, and divides $X^2-3X+2$.

If it is quadratic, you must have $tr(X)=3, \det(X)=2$ and this gives all the solutions in this case.

If it is linear, then it is $X-\lambda$ for $\lambda$ being one of the roots you described. In this case, your matrix having this linear minimal polynomial means
$$X= \lambda I$$
giving the two complex solutions.

Comment: I don't know what a minimal polynomial is. I expanded the other part to get $(2a+a^2-b^2-d^2-c^2+3)+(2b+2ab)i+(2ac+2c)j+(2ad+2d)k$ but I don't really see how to simplify this at all using my known solutions.

Comment: @AColoredReptile If this equals zero then....